# Python library for syntax highlighting

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, pygments

Which Python library for syntax highlighting is the best one? I'm interested in things like supported languages, ease of use, pythonic design, dependencies, development status,  etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [pygments](http://pygments.org/) is the greatest choice. It supports a large number of languages and it's very mature.